# SQL - How to get record count for each day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns all records for the week which starts on Monday.  I'm trying to get the record count for each day of the week with no success.

The Original Query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Beginning of week is Monday
SELECT DateTime, ScanPoints, PostPoints 
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  AND DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND UserID = '1' AND BeerID = '3'
  ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

I've tried several things including Count(DateTime) with a Group By:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Beginning of week is Monday
SELECT Count(DateTime), ScanPoints, PostPoints 
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  AND DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND UserID = '1' AND BeerID = '3'
  ORDER BY DateTime ASC
  GROUP BY DateTime
```

The error indicates there is a syntax error near GROUP.

Comment: ... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has a few issues,

1. GROUP BY must come before ORDER BY.
2. Non-aggregated columns selected must also be in the GROUP BY clause

   ```
   SELECT Count(DateTime), ScanPoints, PostPoints... 
   GROUP BY ScanPoints, PostPoints
   ```
3. I assume your column DateTime actually contains a date and time.  Grouping By this will give you a record for each unique date/time value in your data.  Since you're wanting daily data, you should strip off the time by converting it to a date.  By the way, DateTime is a data type and a terrible name for a column.
4. I prefer not to use DATEFIRST as it does not affect all of the date functions equally.  If you later use a datediff with weeks, the results may be wrong.

My company also uses Monday as the start of the week.  By calculating the shifted first day of the week, you can change which week a Sunday belongs to.

```
CAST(DATEADD( DAY, 
             (DATEPART( WEEKDAY, [YourDate] ) + 5) % 7 * -1,
             [YourDate] ) 
    AS DATE) AS FirstDayOfWeekIsMonday
```

Using the FirstDayOfWeekIsMonday column for your week filtering/grouping will ensure that the Sunday is associated with the prior Monday.

As an added bonus, this expression is SARGable so indexes on YourDate can still be used.

Answer (score 0):

**Group by should appear before Order by.**

Your Query should be build as below:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Beginning of week is Monday

SELECT Count(DateTime), ScanPoints, PostPoints 
FROM SmartTappScanLog  
WHERE DateTime >= 
       dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
    AND DateTime <  
       dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
    AND UserID = '1' AND BeerID = '3'
GROUP BY DateTime
ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try ( Not tested)

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Beginning of week is Monday
SELECT datepart(dw, DateTime) as Day, ScanPoints, PostPoints, Count(DateTime) as Recs,
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  AND DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND UserID = '1' AND BeerID = '3'
  GROUP BY datepart(dw, DateTime) , ScanPoints, PostPoints
  ORDER BY datepart(dw, DateTime) , ScanPoints, PostPoints
```

Comment: I removed the comma after Recs.  The query still returns row for each record for a given day. Not one row with record count for the day.  I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: I don't know the data structure you are working with it could be that the scanponts and datapoints fields are causing the repeating items, you can remove them form the select and group by clauses